# how to add subfolders inside in-app-purchase iOS package?

Tags: in-app-purchase

For some reason, any files I put inside my IAP package (hosted on Apple) under a subfolder, gets eventually downloaded directly under the iOS temporary Contents folder.

I've created a simple IAP package using xcode template which initially had the following directory structure:

```
projectname/projectname/ContentInfo.plist
```

I then placed some extra files in the package under a subdir like so:

```
projectname/projectname/dir1/file1.txt
```

Then I go to xcode->add files->select dir1 and check "create groups" for added folders. All is ok so far. When I look at xcode, I see a group called "dir1", its location relative to group is "dir1" and full path is correctly set to xxxx/dir1.

I also see "file1.txt" with its location relative to group is "file1.txt" and full path correctly set to xxxx/dir1/file1.txt.

I package everything and upload to Apple.

I run a test to download the package and set a breakpoint after the content has been downloaded. I run a file scan function to list all the files. This is what I see under the xxx.zip/Contents folder that iOS creates:

```
ContentInfo.plist
file1.txt
```

dir1 is missing and file1.txt is directly under Contents!

I decided then to reopen the package xcode created (xcarchive) using "Show Package Contents" and indeed I see file1 under Contents/ and not under Contents/dir1...

How do I get the package to retain the directory structure when it's built?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after several hours, found the answer:
I needed to remove the file and group references and re-create them by "adding files" to the project, selecting dir1 folder with "create folder references", not "create groups" option.
After re-packaging this way, the folders were retained inside the package!